# Remapping space + ijkl to arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to set my keyboard so that pressing space and releasing will emit a "normal" space, but holding space and pressing one of `i/j/k/l` will emit an arrow key.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of (Or at least related to) http://superuser.com/questions/371150/space-as-modifier-key-xkb

Answer (score 3):

I guess [the SpaceFN layout](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=51069.0) is exactly what you want. The idea is great and you can customize the layout for your fit. However, it seems that it only works for some specific programmable mechanical keyboard.

For an implementation with software, you can try Karabiner on OSX and Autohotkey on Windows. I'm not very familiar with xkb for Linux, but I guess there are ways to do it as well.